# Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart

Tags: ubuntu, apt, landscape

Any idea why `landscape-server-quickstart` isn't being found?

According to both this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549809/how-do-i-install-landscape-for-personal-use) and [the official Landscape 15.11 installation instructions](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/), the following commands should install Landscape on a local server:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/15.11
apt-get update
apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

I run the above as `root` so I don't need `sudo`, but the result is:

```
root@myserver:~# apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04 for ARM (a Cubox).  Adding the repo initially was only a partial success, giving me a `NO_PUBKEY` error, so I [manually added it with `apt-key` per this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/358424/169836).

Even after several `apt-get update`s and a reboot, the only landscape-ish packages available are

```
# apt-cache search landscape
landscape-client - The Landscape administration system client
landscape-client-ui - The Landscape administration system client - UI configuration
landscape-client-ui-install - The Landscape administration system client - UI installer
landscape-common - The Landscape administration system client - Common files
libunity-core-6.0-9 - core library for the Unity interface
libunity-core-6.0-dev - Core library for the Unity interface - development files
python-txlongpoll - Long polling HTTP frontend for AMQP
unity - Interface designed for efficiency of space and interaction.
unity-services - Services for the Unity interface
cloud-install-landscape - Ubuntu Cloud installer (landscape) - dependency package
gff2aplot - pair-wise alignment-plots for genomic sequences in PostScript
gimp-plugin-registry - repository of optional extensions for GIMP
hedgewars - Funny turn-based artillery game, featuring fighting Hedgehogs!
muttprint - Pretty printing of mails
saga - System for Automated Geoscientific Analyses
thin-client-config-agent - Retrieve the list of remote desktop servers for a user.
xmountains - Fractal landscape generator for X
landscape-api - Tool to access the Landscape API
landscape-hashids - initial package databases for landscape-server
landscape-opendaylight-binaries - OpenDaylight static binary files
```

Comment: I also have the same problem on fresh ubuntu install

Comment: @prodigerati is it Ubuntu 14.04 for ARM?  Or x86/amd64?  It seems like this may be an ARM limitation (ie not all required packages have a build for ARM)